# Is $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ a $F_{\delta}$ set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, baire-category

Recall that an $F_{\sigma}$ set is, by definition, a countable union of closed sets.  We see that $\mathbb{Q}$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set: $\mathbb{Q} = \cup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{q\}$.  Is $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ an $F_{\sigma}$ set? Note: $\mathbb{Q}$ and anything in $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ are hollow.

I have no idea how to do this.  I know the goal is to use Baire Caegory Theorem.  I think that since anything in $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is hollow, we have that $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is a collection of hollow sets, $\{F_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. **I don't know how to show the sets are closed or the collection is countable.**  Then by Baire Category Theorem, we know that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is hollow, but $\mathbb{Q}$ being hollow means $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is dense

$\mathbb{Q}$ is hollow, that tells us that $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is dense (which seems to contradict the note, but maybe I'm just not reading it right).

If this isn't the best way to approach the problem, please let me know the better alternative.

EDIT: I think it might be best to prove it as such:
Suppose $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is a $F_{\sigma}$ set.  Then $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} \cup \mathbb{Q}$ is a countable collection of closed collow sets so by Baire Categoty Theorem, the union of this collection of sets is hollow, but $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} \cup \mathbb{Q}$ is just $mathbb{R}$, which we know is dense, so we've reached a contradiction

Comment: What does "hollow" mean? (And yes, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ *is* dense.) Have you seen the proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a $G_\delta$ set? (Also, in your second sentence, delta should be $\sigma$ and $\cap$ should be $\cup$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber A set is hollow if it has empty interior.  No I have not. And yes it should be sigma.  I've fixed it

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes! Typo! I've fixed it

Comment: @VinnyChase You should also change the "$\cap$" to $\cup$." Having empty interior is not the same as being non-dense; in fact, a set is dense iff its complement has no interior, so the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is hollow means that $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is dense and the fact that $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is hollow means that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense. They're both both hollow and dense.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm confused.  They're both hollow and dense? In our notes it says A dense iff X \ A is hollow

Comment: @VinnyChase Yes,that's what I wrote in my comment ("a set is dense iff its complement has no interior"). They are both hollow and they are both dense. Your notes are correct, but there's no problem with a set being both hollow and dense at the same time.